# Why is this function producing a value of 'Inf'?

Tags: matlab

I have the following function below which I need to translate into MATLAB code, I'm pretty sure I've got the function translated properly. However I've got a small issue with the code.

Function to translate:

[image: equation]

When I attempt to run this function the value of phi comes out as being `inf` I'm really not sure why this is happening?

Also, can someone tell me if I'm doing the right thing with the sum part of this function? In my mind this is telling me to apply this function to every value and then take that value and add it to phi, but I'm not sure if that's what I'm actually doing.

```
function [exists] = detectHaarWatermark(watermarkedCoefs, watermark)

    coefsSize = size(watermarkedCoefs,1);

    phi = 0;
    numeratorTotal = 0;
    denomanatorTotal = 0;

    for i = 1 : coefsSize
        for j = 1 : coefsSize

            y = watermarkedCoefs(i,j) %Watermarked coefficient
            w = watermark(i,j) %Watermark

%             val = ((w * sign(y))^2) / (w^2)

            numerator = (w * sign(y))
            numeratorTotal = numeratorTotal + numerator;
            numeratorTotal = numeratorTotal^2;

            denomanator = (w^2)
            denomanatorTotal = denomanatorTotal + denomanator;


            val = numeratorTotal / denomanatorTotal;

            phi = val;

        end
    end

    phi

    stdDev = std2(watermarkedCoefs)

    if phi > (10*stdDev)
       exists = true; 
    else
        exists = false;
    end

end %end function
```

Edit:

```
numerator = (sum(sum(watermark.*(sign(watermarkedCoefs)))));    
numerator = power(numerator, 2);

denomanator = sum(sum(watermark.^2));

phi = numerator / denomanator
```

Comment: You can remove the double loop by using element-wise operators (ie `.*` and `.^`) and use the `sum` function on the resulting matrices. I think that might solve quite a few issues.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the inputs, which would seem to be critical here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I'd go about changing the code to implement these changes, could you show me? Using matrix operations is still something I'm new to.

Comment: For example, with no loop, `denominator = sum(sum(watermark.^2));` If phi still comes out `Inf` with working calculation, it's because this denominator value is zero and that's entirely down to your input

Comment: I've just had a go at using matrix operations actually, this is what I have `phi = ((watermark.*(sign(watermarkedCoefs))^2 / (watermark.^2)));` where do the sum functions need to go?

Comment: Look at your equation. The sum is inside the square on the top and outside it on the bottom. So put the `sum` functions in the same place (for a 2D matrix you need to sum twice to get the total as `sum` works in one dimension at a time)

Comment: I've just edited the main post with new code that uses matrix operations, would you mind having a look and telling me if it looks okay? I appreciate your help.

Comment: your `phi` calculation looks better now. If you are still getting `Inf` then your input data is the cause.

Comment: Phi is producing a proper value now, and the function seems to work as intended. I appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Please post your edit as the answer, so it is clear that this question is resolved.